# Создать координатную сетку на Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть Canvas. На него можно дропать изображения. Потом их двигать, изменять размеры и т.д. Вопрос. Как наилучшим образом создать и отобразить на Canvas сетку, размерами скажем 10 на 10 точек? И как потом к ней сделать "прилипание" расположенных на canvas контролов? При условии что:

1. свойство Background канвы занято цветом фона (что логично), и кисть туда не положишь.
2. С DrawingBrush вообще проблемы, в том плане что на стареньком железе, на win XP, сетка нарисованная через DrawingBrush, не хочет рисоваться. А надо. На более современных компьютерах рисуется.

Уточняю по просьбам трудящихся. Нужен наиболее оптимальный способ (алгоритм) создать нарисованную сетку на элементе Canvas с использованием net3.5. И способ осуществить прилипание элементов канвы к ней. Я считал что простая отрисовка линий на канве будет подтормаживать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вам нужна сетка переменного размера, подпишитесь на изменение размеров `Canvas`'а и рисуйте вручную:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Background"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainCanvas}"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MainCanvas}"
            SizeChanged="UpdateBackPattern"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public YourControlConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UpdateBackPattern(null, null);
}

void UpdateBackPattern(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var w = Background.ActualWidth;
    var h = Background.ActualHeight;

    Background.Children.Clear();
    for (int x = 10; x < w; x += 10)
        AddLineToBackground(x, 0, x, h);
    for (int y = 10; y < h; y += 10)
        AddLineToBackground(0, y, w, y);
}

void AddLineToBackground(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    var line = new Line()
    {
        X1 = x1, Y1 = y1,
        X2 = x2, Y2 = y2,
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 1,
        SnapsToDevicePixels = true
    };
    line.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
    Background.Children.Add(line);
}
```

Для «прилипания» вам нужно проверять координаты перемещаемого объекта, и если они близки к сетке (то есть, `x % <шаг сетки> < <расстояние прилипания>` или `x % <шаг сетки> > <шаг сетки> - <расстояние прилипания>`) приводить его координату к кратной размеру сетки.

Comment: На удивление быстро работает. Не ожидал. Еще протестирую на более слабом железе. Хотя я и надеялся сыскать более изящный вариант что-ли.

Comment: @Victor: Угу, вручную иногда получается быстрее. Изящнее не придумал, сорри.