# WPF: Реализация координатной сетки в редакторе

Tags: c#, wpf

Привет!
Поставлена задача: есть графический редактор схем, необходимо реализовать прорисовку координатной сетки и привязку к ней(ну то есть координаты элементов подстраиваются под сетку при перетаскивании).

Есть класс `SizedCanvas`, который наследуется от `Canvas`. Главная рабочая область - это объект canvasWorkspace типа `SizedCanvas`.

Отрисовку реализую с помощью класса, который наследуется от `Adorner` и перегружает метод `onRender`. Пока что так делал, но цикл вообще нужно заменить.

```
class LineGridAdorner : Adorner
{
    public int step { get; set; } //Шаг сетки
    public double width { get; set; } //Ширина поля
    public double height { get; set; } //Высота поля

    private Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Coral, 0.2);

    public LineGridAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        step = 50;

        pen.DashStyle = DashStyles.Dash;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x * step, 0), new Point(x * step, 1000));
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, x * step), new Point(2000, x * step));
        }
    }
}
```

Вот кусок кода, который вызывается после того, как все элементы на холсте отрендерены:

```
private void canvasWorkspace_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lineGrid = new LineGridAdorner(canvasWorkspace);
    lineGrid.height = canvasWorkspace.ActualHeight;
    lineGrid.width = canvasWorkspace.ActualWidth;
    lineGrid.step = 50;

    layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(canvasWorkspace);
    layer.Add(lineGrid);
    isGridShown = true;
}
```

Собственно, и рендер почти сделан, и привязка почти дописана. Проблема в том, что это очень лагает. Т.е. при отрисовке кадров(а это происходит и при перемещении объекта и при его выделении) срабатывает цикл, который грубо говоря выполняется 100 раз, и отрисовывает 2 линии за цикл. Это затратно, лагает и никуда не годиться. Как можно оптимизировать все это?
Теоретически, если бы я знал диапазон координат(верхний элемент - `ScrollerView`, поле `Content` которого - `canvasWorkspace`), которые в данный момент видны, то мог бы что-нибудь придумать.

Comment: Вот эта реализация у меня не лагает: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459763/10105